# Mimic adjustedContentInset on iOS 10?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uikit, ios10

I'm looking modify the size and position of a `tableView`'s cell's subview  from `scrollViewDidScroll(_:)` by measuring the `contentOffset`. The `contentOffset` seems to jump to a non-zero value the first time that `scrollViewDidScroll(_:)` is called.

For a `UITableView` within `UINavigationController`, `adjustedContentInset` on iOS 11 correctly allows me to calculate the relative `contentOffset` when scrolling the `tableView`.

For example, if I scroll the `tableView`, I can calculate the precise amount that it was scrolled like this:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    var adjustedTopInset: CGFloat = 0.0
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        adjustedTopInset = scrollView.adjustedContentInset.top
    }
    let deltaY = scrollView.contentOffset.y - adjustedTopInset
}
```

The thing is, as `adjustedContentInset` is only available on iOS 11, how do you calculate this same relative scroll amount on iOS 10?

In `viewDidLoad()` the `contentOffset` of the `tableView` is `CGPointZero`, but the first time that `scrollViewDidScroll(_:)` is called, the `contentOffset.y` jumps to a value that is the height of the navigation bar and the status bar. On iOS 11 `adjustedContentInset` helps by providing that height.

How can I calculate this on iOS 10?

Comment: @matt unfortunately that is reported as (0,0,0,0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sound as if this might be an "x-y" problem. You haven't explained what you're really trying to do, but the mention of `viewDidLoad` suggests that you are trying to get some measurement value in `viewDidLoad` so as to know later how much that measurement has changed. But you cannot measure *anything* in `viewDidLoad`; it's too early. Postpone the measurement until the first call to `viewDidAppear` and you will then have a correct starting value.

Comment: I added an opening sentence indicating what I'm trying to achieve. Also, I'm not actually measuring anything in viewDidLoad for use programmatically - just observing that the contentOffset was 0.0. I'll try viewDidAppear now

Comment: you are totally correct, viewDidAppear properly reports the contentOffset, thanks.